# Accessing C nested structs in Python after interfacing with SWIG

Tags: python, c, swig

**Preface**:

I have two header files: "Sample.h" and "Sample2.h". Here are the contents of the two headers:

1. "Sample.h" has:

```
#include "Sample2.h"

typedef struct {
    int c;
    sJustFloats sJf;
}sTest;
```

1. "Sample2.h" has:

```
typedef struct {
    float a;
    float b;
}sJustFloats;
```

2. Sample.c just has:

```
#include "Sample.h"
```

4. My SWIG interface file has:

```
%module Sample
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
#include "Sample.h"
%}
%include "Sample.h"

%apply float {float a}; // For sJustFloats.a
%apply float {float b}; // For sJustFloats.b
%apply int {int c};     // For sTest.c
%apply sJustFloats {sJustFloats sJf}; // For sTest.sJf
%apply sTest {sTest test}; //I guess this exposes test struct itself.
```

5. Steps followed to get .so file that is imported in Python:

```
gcc -c -fPIC Sample.c Sample_wrap.c -I /usr/include/python3.6m
ld -shared Sample.o Sample_wrap.o -o _Sample.so
```

**Observations**:

I am able to import this as a module in Python and I can access fields of sTest as follows:

```
test = Sample.sTest()
test.c // To access "c" -- This works fine
```

**Problem: I am not able to access fields of struct *sJustFloats***

If I do `test.sJf()`, it gives me  `TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not callable`. Similarly `test.sJf.a` gives: `AttributeError: 'SwigPyObject' object has no attribute 'a'`

Can someone please tell me how to access members of the struct, sJustFloats?

**Additional observations:**

- When I do  `type(Sample.sTest)`, it gives me `<class 'type'>`, whereas doing `type(Sample.sTest.sJf)` gives me `<class 'property'>`.
- If I have both structs in the same file "Sample.h", I am able to access all the fields by doing:

```
test = Sample.sTest()
sjf = test.sJf()
sjf.a # Works fine
sjf.b # Works fine
```

Am I missing something in the interface file? Are there are nuances of SWIG that I'm unaware of?

Comment: i dont remember if swig parses includes recursively. Did you try to also `#include "Sample2.h"` in the interface file?

Comment: As it turns out, it does. : ) I tried adding #include "Sample2.h" in the interface file, that resulted in a "conflicting types for 'sJustFloats'", "previous declaration here" during compilation with gcc.
May be it was not explicit enough in the question, but from Python, I am able to see sJustFloats. sTest has an integer and sJf. It's just that I'm not able to access any of the fields within sJf.

Comment: sry I meant `%include "Sample2.h"`

Comment: No, SWIG doesn’t recurse by default, but you need `%include "Sample2.h"` after `%include "Sample.h"` and don’t need any of the %apply

Comment: btw afaik the advantage of swig is that its supports bindings from and to many languages. For only Python calling C there are easier to use alternatives

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, what other alternatives would you suggest? My intention is to expose a bunch of structures and APIs from an existing project in C for use in Python

Comment: acutally I do not know C. I just suppose that there must exist simpler alternatives also for C because they do for C++ (I only came here because the question was mistagged as C++)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, can you please post "%include "Sample2.h" as an answer, I'll mark it. 
It seems to be working! : )

Comment: @MarkTolonen, you were right. It does not. By adding %include "Sample2.h", it started working.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see. I know what you mean by easier alternatives. I recently successfully interfaced with C++ APIs with PyBind. This being in C, people suggested SWIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG doesn’t recurse by default, but you need `%include "Sample2.h"` after `%include "Sample.h"` and don’t need any of the `%apply`:

```
%module Sample

%{
#include "Sample.h"
%}

%include "Sample.h"
%include "Sample2.h"
```